# How to throttle S3 & Glacier upload/download speeds with boto?

Tags: python, boto

I'm using boto to upload and download files to S3 & Glacier.

How can I ratelimit/throttle the uploading and downloading speeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No directly usable solution seems to be present

Disclaimer: I am using boto for S3 rather often and have also experience with Amazon Glacier. I have also reviewed current version of boto and checked quickly source code to have current knowledge, however there is slight chance, I could be wrong.

- none of S3 and Amazon Glacier download and upload methods provide an option to throttle speed.
- There is notion of res_download_handler, which can handle downloads of S3 objects, but the only available implementation of such handler in boto is ResumableDownloadHandler.
- for Amazon Glacier there is file an issue [Please add ability to throttle upload bandwidth used by the glacier client](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1625)  which is accepted, but still open.

## Searching for possible solutions

### Write your own download handler

This could work for S3 download as these methods allow setting up such handler.

You would have to write such handler yourself.

### For S3, use `cb` parameter with "a bit blocking" behaviour

Functions for uploading and downloading S3 objects provide a parameter `cb`, where you can define a function to call repeatedly after certain amount of data was uploaded/downloaded.

Theoretically, it could be possible to create such a callable, which would register time and amount of data since last call and wait for some time to throttle the speed.

I did not find similar option for Amazon Glacier.

Comment: That's a shame. Do you think creating a proxy that would throttle connections could be a simpler option?

Comment: @jbrown Personally, I would not call it shape (I am really glad, `boto` provides what it I need). Regarding proxy, I would try to find an existing solution, I had an experience of writing Python based proxy application which has worked, but comparing to nginx solution was very very slow.

Comment: A proxy might be a lot of work. I'll have a look at modifying the existing uploader/downloader classes that boto provides. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jbrown I would personally try the callback function. This seems to me the easiest way to start.

Comment: I'll start with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to use traffic shaping tools under linux, like tc.  These tools let you control bandwidth and even simulate network packet loss or even long distance communication issues.   Easy to write a python script to control the port behavior via a shell.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a rate limiting progress class for the s3 boto python library as follows:  It assumes that your rate per second is higher than the rate limit and seems to mostly work ok.

```
class ProgressPercentage(object):
    def __init__(self, rate_limit=-1):
        self._seen_so_far = 0
        self.rate_limit = rate_limit
        self.bytes_check = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self.check_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __call__(self, bytes_amount):
        with self._lock:
            self._seen_so_far += bytes_amount

            if self.rate_limit > 0:
                # assumes one thread
                self.bytes_check += bytes_amount
                elapsed_time = datetime.datetime.now() - self.check_time
                total_seconds = elapsed_time.total_seconds()
                if self.bytes_check > self.rate_limit:
                    if total_seconds < 1:
                        time.sleep(1.0 - total_seconds)
                    self.bytes_check = 0
                    self.check_time = datetime.datetime.now()

            if sys.stderr.isatty():
                sys.stderr.write(
                    "\r{0}".format(size_str(self._seen_so_far)))
                sys.stderr.flush()
```

Call as in this example to limit to 100k per second:

```
s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket_name, key, Callback=ProgressPercentage(100000))
```